# How can we automate login to IBM System using Python?

Tags: python, websphere, ibm-midrange

I need to login to IBM i System using Python without entering the username and password manually.

I used py3270 library but it is not able to detect the Emulator wc3270. The emulator I use has .hod extension and opens with IBM i Launcher.
Can anyone help me with this? what could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Techie Please be aware that while IBM i supports 3270 connections, the native way of terminal communications is 5250.

Comment: What do you plan to do with Python once you are logged in? (I ask this because your question doesn't have enough information for me to be really sure what you're asking.)

Comment: The question has a websphere tag. How does Websphere fit into the question? My point is that generally speaking, Websphere is a web front end, does not use either 5250 or 3270, and typically interacts with IBM i via the database. Are you really interested in accessing the database, or accessing a green screen menu/program?

Comment: I want to access the green screen menu to automate few tasks.

Comment: Launching (local) programs and automating keystrokes can be done with Python, but is better achieved using AutoHotkey. Yes, it's another language to learn, but it's not hard. The more fundamental goal (automating tasks on an IBM i) is *best* achieved by finding out what those menu options are doing (issuing commands, running programs, manipulating the database in some way, etc.) and writing something that does those things directly, not through any user interface. Python with pyodbc is a good way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.system() is a blocking statement. That is, it blocks, or stops further Python code from being executed until whatever os.system() is doing has completed. This problem needs us to spawn a separate thread, so that the Windows process executing the ACS software runs at the same time the rest of the Python code runs. subprocess is one Python library that can handle this.

Here is some code that opens an ACS 5250 terminal window and pushes the user and password onto that window. There's no error checking, and there are some setup details that my system assumes about ACS which your system may not.

```
# the various print() statements are for looking behind the scenes 

import sys
import time
import subprocess
from pywinauto.application import Application
import pywinauto.keyboard as keyboard

userid = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]

print("Starting ACS")
cmd = r"C:\Users\Public\IBM\ClientSolutions\Start_Programs\Windows_x86-64\acslaunch_win-64.exe"
system = r'/system="your system name or IP goes here"'
# Popen requires the command to be separate from each of the parameters, so an array
result = subprocess.Popen([cmd, r"/plugin=5250",system], shell=True)
print(result)

# wait at least long enough for Windows to get past the splash screen
print("ACS starting - pausing")
time.sleep(5)

print("connecting to Windows process")
ACS = Application().connect(path=cmd)
print(ACS)

# debugging
windows = ACS.windows()
print(windows)

dialog = ACS['Signon to IBM i']
print(dialog)

print("sending keystrokes")
keyboard.send_keys(userid)
keyboard.send_keys("{TAB}") 
keyboard.send_keys(password)
keyboard.send_keys("{ENTER}")
 
print('Done.')
```

Comment: This worked with few changes...but it is not reliable since if the window does not open it still sends the keystrokes...Can we modify it such that it sends keys to the ACS window only?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am facing the same issue. I was able to run the IBMi (ACS), however, once it run, my python script stop functioning as if the app is preventing the python from being running. In generally speaking, the app seems to not detecting the script.But once I closed the app, my python script continue to work.. I put some indication e.g timesleep, however as i mentioned earlier, it only continue to that line of code once IBM is closed. There will be few lines to be added to move the selection to 5250 and inject the credential.

*I tried with pyautogui, still facing the same issue. so now i tried pywinauto import keyboard .

```
#Variables
dir = sys.argv[1]
username = sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]
x = dir.split("\\")

print(x[-1])
command = "cd \ && cd Users/Public/Desktop && " + '"' + x[-1] + '"'
print(command)  
os.system(command)

------ FROM THIS LINE OF CODE ONWARDS, IT STOPPED RUNNING ONCE IBM IS LAUNCHED ---

print('TIME START')
time.sleep(5)
print('TIME END')

keyboard.send_keys(username)
keyboard.send_keys(password)
keyboard.send_keys("{ENTER}") 
print('Done.')
```

Appreciate your help to look into this matter. Thanks

Comment: Please post questions as questions, not answers. Thanks!

Comment: Try this: pls check command.. I think u r giving wrong command. cmd = r"C:\Users\Public\IBM\ClientSolutions\Start_Programs\Windows_x86-64\acslaunch_win-64.exe"(or the path of win-32.exe) whichever is the one or try both which works.
system = r'/system="your system name or IP goes here"' give hostname here

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. @BuckCalabro, alright noted. My bad. Thanks