# How to access 5250 session via Python which is opened via Host on Demand?

Tags: python, automation, ibm-midrange, mainframe, terminal-emulator

How to use py3270 for setting up a connection to 5250 emulator? I installed the library and used this code https://pypi.org/project/py3270/. But it gives error "Windows cannot find wc3270. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Also there is another library p5250 - https://github.com/simonfaltum/p5250. Anyone has tried it? Not able to setup a connection with this as well.

Does anyone know how to access 5250 session via Python which is opened via Host on Demand?

Comment: This project seems to have a dependency to an emulator (wc3270), which you need to install and add to the the `PATH` so it can be found, as the project page states - `The x3270 executables need to be on your PATH!`. The Project page mentions this http://x3270.bgp.nu/

Comment: I have already added that in the path...but still not resolved.

Comment: have you restarted after updating the PATH? After you have restarted, when you open a command prompt and try to start the application wc3270 do you get the same error or does it find it? To me it seems like a problem with the envirnment

Comment: 3270 and 5250 are two distinct display data stream protocols of IBM. 3270 is used with IBM Mainframes, aka IBM Z Systems. 5250 is used with IBM Midrange systems, aka IBM i platform. You'd need to use the py5250 library instead of py3270 to communicate with 5250 devices. Search the internet for "xxxx IBM display data stream", where xxxx is either 3270, or 5250, to get links.

Comment: There is no py5250 library..Please share links if we can connect through ACS using Python

Comment: I was guessing there was a py5250 equivlent to py3270. It seesm the library is calle p5250. Googling "python p5250" returned a couple of links. I have never worked with 5250s, so I' drather not start commeting on those links, but this one might give you a start [A Python library to access IBM i / AS400 hosts with a TN5250 emulator.](https://github.com/simonfaltum/p5250). I only ever used 3270s.

Comment: This is clearly another followup to [How can we automate login to IBM System using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75157007/how-can-we-automate-login-to-ibm-system-using-python). Voting to close.